# vbscript - unable to extract a number from text file

Tags: vbscript

I would like to check a txt file for a string.
If the string doesn't exist, it takes a number from key.txt and write it in another file. That part works fine.

But when the string is found, I would like to read the first five characters into a variable and take this variable to creating xml. When I run my script and the string is found.... the xml element Key is empty...

Anyone can help me? Thanks

```
Dim FSSys, Reference, corp, Account, intCorp, strPK, FS
Set FSSys = Wscript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")   
Set Reference = FSSys.OpenTextFile("C:\corpreferenz.txt")   
intCorp = Reference.ReadAll
Reference.Close

intCorp = intCorp + 1

Set corp = FSSys.CreateTextFile("C:\corpreferenz.txt")   
corp.Write intCorp
corp.Close

Const FORREADING = 1
Const FORWRITING = 2
Const FORAPPENDING = 8

Dim sToSearch: sToSearch = "Test"
Dim sFileName: sFileName = "C:\Account.txt" 
Dim sContent, Found, TxtFile

If Not FSSys.FileExists(sFileName) Then 
    MsgBox "File Not Found"
    WScript.Quit 0
End If

Set TxtFile = FSSys.OpenTextFile(sFileName,FORREADING)
sContent = TxtFile.ReadAll

If InStr(sContent,sToSearch) Then 
    Found = True 
    while not TxtFile.AtEndOfStream
        sTemp = TxtFile.ReadLine
        If Instr(1,sTemp,sToSearch)>0 then
            strPK = strPK + sTemp
            FS = Left(strPK, 5)
        End If
    Wend
End If


Set TxtFile = Nothing

If Not Found Then 
    Set PKNumber = FSSys.OpenTextFile("C:\Key.txt")
    intPKNumber = PKNumber.ReadAll
    PKNumber.Close
    intPKNumber = intPKNumber + 1
    Set PKNum = FSSys.CreateTextFile("C:\Key.txt")
    PKNum.Write intPKNumber
    PKNum.Close
    FS = intPKNumber
    Set TxtFile = FSSys.OpenTextFile(sFileName,FORAPPENDING)
    TxtFile.WriteLine intPKNumber & " " & sToSearch
End If


'Create XML
set xml = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
set encoding = xml.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0'")
xml.insertBefore encoding, xml.childNodes.Item(0)
set foo = xml.createElement("XML")
set bar = xml.createElement("Table")
set corp = xml.createElement("Corp")
set cdata = xml.createCDATASection(intCorp)
set konto = xml.createElement("Key")
set cdata1 = xml.createCDATASection(FS)
corp.appendChild cdata
bar.appendChild corp
konto.appendChild cdata1
bar.appendChild konto
foo.appendChild bar
xml.appendChild(foo)

xmlSave xml, "C:BUP.xml"

'Function for XML
function xmlSave(xml, filename)
    set rdr = CreateObject("MSXML2.SAXXMLReader")
    set wrt = CreateObject("MSXML2.MXXMLWriter")
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.STREAM")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Charset = "ISO-8859-1"

    wrt.indent = True
    wrt.encoding = "ISO-8859-1"
    wrt.output = oStream
    Set rdr.contentHandler = wrt
    Set rdr.errorHandler = wrt

    rdr.Parse xml
    wrt.flush

    oStream.SaveToFile filename, 2
end function
```

Answer (score 0):

After

```
sContent = TxtFile.ReadAll
```

you (the read pointer) are at the end of the file; `TxtFile.AtEndOfStream` is True and `TxtFile.ReadLine` won't be called/would fail. Evidence:

```
>> Set f = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(WScript.ScriptFullName)
>> WScript.Echo 0, CStr(f.AtEndOfStream)
>> s = f.ReadAll()
>> WScript.Echo 1, CStr(f.AtEndOfStream)
>>
0 Falsch (False)
1 Wahr (True)
```

You could loop over the lines of the file (Split() sContent on vbCrLf), or - better - use a RegExp on sContent to extract the data needed.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I have not realized that the pointer is at the end... I solved the issue!